# Power BI Range Lookup

Tags: powerbi, dax, lookup

I am calling out to all Microsoft BI experts out there.
I know there is a DAX formula for lookup in Power BI, but currently I'm a rookie in the BI world, and I want to know if there is a possibility to lookup from ranges as we can do in Excel (searching in multiple columns).

I have the below example, I need data from the below table:

|  | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021.01.04 | A | C | B |
| 2021.01.05 | A | C | B |
| 2021.01.06 | A | C | B |
| 2021.01.07 | A | C | B |

In T2 I have a Date and a number

| Date | Number |
| --- | --- |
| 2021.01.04 | 1 |
| 2021.01.04 | 2 |
| 2021.01.04 | 3 |

I want to lookup the result based on the date and the respective number:

```
2021.01.04 & 1 = A
2021.01.04 & 2 = C
2021.01.04 & 3 = B
```

Can anyone help me with this?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

First unpivot header row in power query

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Ashok\Power BI\Stack Overflow\data_22_oct_21.xlsx"), null, true),
    Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item="Sheet1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Sheet1_Sheet,{{"Column1", type date}, {"Column2", type any}, {"Column3", type any}, {"Column4", type any}}),
    #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Changed Type"),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Transposed Table", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Column1", Int64.Type}, {"1/4/2021", type text}, {"1/5/2021", type text}, {"1/6/2021", type text}, {"1/7/2021", type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type1", {"Column1"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{{"Column1", "Number"}, {"Attribute", "Date"}}),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns",{{"Date", type date}})
in
    #"Changed Type2"
```

Then write LOOKUPVALUE Dax to evaluate result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With `DAX`

If you have following two tables respectively called `t1` and `t2`

| t1.Date | t1.1 | t1.2 | t1.3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-04 | A | B | Z |
| 2021-01-05 | B | C | A |
| 2021-01-06 | C | A | B |
| 2021-06-07 | A | B | C |

| t2.Date | t2.Number |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-04 | 1 |
| 2021-01-04 | 2 |
| 2021-01-04 | 3 |
| 2021-01-05 | 1 |
| 2021-01-05 | 2 |
| 2021-01-05 | 3 |
| 2021-01-06 | 1 |
| 2021-01-06 | 2 |
| 2021-01-06 | 3 |
| 2021-06-07 | 1 |
| 2021-06-07 | 2 |
| 2021-06-07 | 3 |

and you want to achieve the following desired result as depicted in the picture below with the absolute current structure of `t1` and `t2`and not by unpivoting t1 in PQ first, then you can write following 4 measures

```
_1 = MAX(t1[t1.1])

_2 = MAX(t1[t1.2])

_3 = MAX(t1[t1.3])

Measure =
VAR _dateVisible =
    MAX ( t2[t2.Date] )
VAR _numberVisible =
    MAX ( t2[t2.Number] )
VAR _value =
    MAXX (
        SELECTCOLUMNS (
            FILTER ( t1, t1[t1.Date] = _dateVisible ),
            "Date", [t1.Date],
            "Value",
                SWITCH (
                    TRUE (),
                    _numberVisible = 1, [_1],
                    _numberVisible = 2, [_2],
                    _numberVisible = 3, [_3]
                )
        ),
        [Value]
    )
RETURN
    _value
```

which will give you what you need

[image: Solution]